# how to create database(1 CDB and 2 PDB) by dbca silent mode with response file, oracle 12c

Tags: oracle-12c

I want create a new database with 1 CDB and 2 PDB, so i write response file and use dbca tool with silent mode. But it must Manual input PDBADMIN password through terminal and only create 1 CDB and 0 PDB. Here is my response file sample:

```
[GENERAL]
RESPONSEFILE_VERSION=12.1.0
OPERATION_TYPE=createDatabase
[CREATEDATABASE]
GDBNAME=orcl1
SID=orcl1
CREATEASCONTAINERDATABASE=true
NUMBEROFPDBS=2
PDBNAME=pdb1/pdb2
TEMPLATENAME=General_Purpose.dbc
SYSPASSWORD=Welcome1
SYSTEMPASSWORD=Welcome1
EMCONFIGURATION=NONE
DATABASETYPE=MULTIPURPOSE
LISTENERS=LISTENER
```

anybody knows how can fix it?

Comment: Changed the below parameter and test the same > NUMBEROFPDBS=1
> > PDBNAME=pdb1

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a 'pdbAdminPassword' parameter to your response file.

The following worked for me:

```
[oracle@ora12c66 CDBORCL]$ dbca -silent -createPluggableDatabase -sourceDB cdborcl  -pdbName pdb4 -createPDBFrom default  -pdbAdminUserName pdb4  -pdbAdminPassword qwe123 -createUserTableSpace true -sampleSchema true -TEMPLATENAME General_Purpose.dbc
Creating Pluggable Database 
4% complete
12% complete
21% complete
38% complete
85% complete
Completing Pluggable Database Creation
100% complete
Look at the log file "/u01/cfgtoollogs/dbca/cdborcl/pdb4/cdborcl0.log" for further details.
```